# How to store the User inputs until a page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple form as below. I am trying to store all the `input` values. I have been trying this as in the snippet but they are not stored.

I want to store the values of all inputs on search and want to use them for the next click of search even user hits the search with empty values or until the page refresh (possibly the former).

Any help or guiding links are much appreciated. TIA!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var lengthValue = $("#wordlength").val();
    var wordValue = $("#word").val().replace(/ /g, '-');
    
    if (wordValue == '') {
      wordValue = sessionStorage.getItem("data");
      if (wordValue == null) {
        wordValue = ' ';
      }
    }
    
    var postionValue = $("#position").val();
    var wordTypeValue = $("#wordtype").val();
    var wordSearchValue = $("#mainword_search").val();
    sessionStorage.setItem('wordtype', wordTypeValue);
    
    if (wordTypeValue == '') {
      wordTypeValue = sessionStorage.getItem('wordtype');
      if (wordTypeValue == null) {
        wordTypeValue = ' ';
      }
    }

    sessionStorage.setItem('length', lengthValue);
    if (lengthValue == '') {
      lengthValue = sessionStorage.getItem('length');
      if (lengthValue == null) {
        lengthValue = ' ';
      }
    }

    sessionStorage.setItem('position', postionValue);
    if (postionValue == '') {
      postionValue = sessionStorage.getItem('position');
      if (postionValue == null) {
        postionValue = ' ';
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="wordlength" placeholder="All" onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==0 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57))">
<select class="form-control" id="wordtype" name="wordtypesearch">
  <option value="">word</option>
  <option value="old">old</option>
  <option value="new">new</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="position" name="positionsearch">
  <option value="containing">Containing</option>
  <option value="starting">Starting With</option>
  <option value="ending">Ending With</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="word" placeholder="Text....">
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit" class="submit px-3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **localStorage** to store ur data not **sessionStorage** like :

```
localStorage.setItem('key', Value)
```

Comment: I no longer want the value when the browser is closed so i'm using session storage instead

Comment: **sessionStorage** and **localStorage**. Please - casing matters.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Stackoverflow's snippet is not good for testing storage functions - it's **sandboxed** and as such cannot get/set storages (localStorage, sessionStorage).

But, if you try it on JSFiddle (or Codepen.io, etc.), then you can see that your code just need a small modification (I added the modifications and commented them):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // add an argument to the click function - I added 'e' for 'event'
  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    // use e.preventDefault() to prevent the submit button doing
    // anything BEFORE your code
    e.preventDefault();
    var lengthValue = $("#wordlength").val();
    var wordValue = $("#word").val().replace(/ /g, '-');

    if (wordValue == '') {
      wordValue = sessionStorage.getItem("data");
      if (wordValue == null) {
        wordValue = ' ';
      }
    }

    var postionValue = $("#position").val();
    var wordTypeValue = $("#wordtype").val();
    var wordSearchValue = $("#mainword_search").val();
    sessionStorage.setItem('wordtype', wordTypeValue);

    if (wordTypeValue == '') {
      wordTypeValue = sessionStorage.getItem('wordtype');
      if (wordTypeValue == null) {
        wordTypeValue = ' ';
      }
    }

    sessionStorage.setItem('length', lengthValue);
    if (lengthValue == '') {
      lengthValue = sessionStorage.getItem('length');
      if (lengthValue == null) {
        lengthValue = ' ';
      }
    }

    sessionStorage.setItem('position', postionValue);
    if (postionValue == '') {
      postionValue = sessionStorage.getItem('position');
      if (postionValue == null) {
        postionValue = ' ';
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="wordlength" placeholder="All" onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==0 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57))">
<select class="form-control" id="wordtype" name="wordtypesearch">
  <option value="">word</option>
  <option value="old">old</option>
  <option value="new">new</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="position" name="positionsearch">
  <option value="containing">Containing</option>
  <option value="starting">Starting With</option>
  <option value="ending">Ending With</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="word" placeholder="Text....">
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit" class="submit px-3">
```

More on **preventDefault()**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Here's the JSFiddle, but it won't be there forever: https://jsfiddle.net/mukagergely/noc52y6u/

You can check sessionStorage there - it works

Comment: This still gives me empty values mate , instead of session stored

Comment: Could you describe what you really want? 1. Store all input values on submit 2. If the user starts the next search, values should be read from sessionStorage, but not overwriting other data entered in the input fields 3. Keep these values until page refresh - is this correct?

Comment: If you want to keep the values until page refresh, then why not just use an object to store the data? Why do you need sessionStorage?

Comment: yes sir , if the user submits with any of field with empty it should take the values from session and the non-empty as he inputs but not from session, hope it is clear

Comment: While the user starts the next search if the fields are empty then it should acquire from the session and the values from user should be as it is

Comment: This fiddle should do the trick: https://jsfiddle.net/mukagergely/591qhnak/ Try changing something -> Search, Refresh page, etc.

Comment: I added a load button so you can try that it doesn't overwrite your data by loading. But I still cannot get you usecase - if you want to keep data until page refresh, then you don't need sessionStorage, only an object to hold the data

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest approach will be to define `variables` in `ready` function and then just overwrite them with selected values.
Exm:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var postionValue;
  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    ......
    postionValue = $("#position").val();
    ......
  }
  ......
  USE IT IN ANOTHER FUNCTION
  ......
}
```

THIS APPROACH WORKS ONLY IF YOU NOT REFRESHING CURRENT SITE

otherwise use @Nader answer [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59972410/9151084)